# Sort Numbers COLOURED ROWS

Tags: numbers, color

I know you can sort columns by their color, but how do you sort ROWS by their colors in Numbers?
Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Different!

It is not possible to sort rows (or columns) by color in Numbers unless you devise an interim scheme such as assigning a number to every color used in a table and entering these numbers to the corresponding row(s) as they are created. In addition, it is also not possible to sort a table's columns in Numbers. There is no mention of either in this [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/numbers/tanb46cee2b1/mac) on sorting in Numbers. If you need to sort a table's columns in Numbers, you need to first transpose the table, sort the rows as desired, and then transpose again.